# JTRevealSidebar push to ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6

I'm using JTRevealSidebar V2 with `UITableView` on the left slide bar.

I don't know how to push to other ViewController by sending a message.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (self.sidebarDelegate) {
       NSString *text = [self.leftList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if ([text isEqual:@"Warenkorb"]) {
            NSLog(@"Ist warenkorb");
           // How to push/create/bring2top view of msCartViewController Identified by "Cart"?
           // NSLog works
        }
    }
}
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

In your rootviewcontroller, you would allocate a new UIViewController and then push it onto the UINavigation stack.

For example:

`UIViewController *myViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];`

myViewController.title = @"My First View";

myViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

//to push the UIView.

[self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];

Remember to do this in your root view controller!
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, your problem is how to get an instance from storyboard, as I see you call your msCartViewController "Cart" in storyboard.

Or Maybe you cannot get your navigation controller for pushing.

For first Problem

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];
msCartViewController* vc=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Cart"];
```

For Second Problem, you need to store your navigation controller pointer to someplace you can visit, like in a dictionary property in a singleton. just like

```
// at first make a singleton with a dictionary property. here I call it YourNavigationCenter

UINavigationController *navigationController = [YourNavigationCenter sharedCenter].navigationDictionary[@"yourNavigationName"];
[navigationController pushViewController:self animated:YES];
```

If these solution have not catch your point, please make a comment.